# Mysql - Compare array elements with field value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a table with structure

```
id | item | order_date | delivery_date
```

And I have an array of dates, for example

```
$dates = array('2015-06-01', '2015-06-11', '2015-06-26');
```

What I need to do is to find count of items which where ordered, but not delivered yet on each date. Because of my code complexity, it is impossible to foreach array and search for each date separately.

There is an example of what I think the query should look like, but I am starting wondering if it is even possible to make it work this way (without foreaching each date).

```
SELECT SUM(id) FROM orders WHERE order_date > IN({implode(",", $dates)}) AND delivery_date < IN ({implode(",", $dates)}) GROUP BY ???
```

**Notice: I would like to GROUP BY each date given in an array.**

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just an example to explain my problem more clearly. I would look for older entries in which delivery_date is filled, for example order_date = 2015-04-30 AND delivery_date = 2015-05-05 (it's an example for dates array given in my question)

Comment: Sorry, but it's as much clear as I could explain

Comment: What you need is `$dates[0] BETWEEN order_date AND delivery_date OR $dates[1] BETWEEN order_date AND delivery_date OR $dates[2] BETWEEN order_date AND delivery_date`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ! But I found out that only temporary table could help me to achieve what I am expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that returns all the dates in the array. Then you can join with that, and use its column in the `GROUP BY`.

```
$subquery = implode(' UNION ', array_map(function($d) {
    return "SELECT '$d' AS date";
}, $d));
$query = "SELECT d.date, SUM(id)
          FROM orders
          JOIN ($subquery) AS d ON d.date BETWEEN order_date AND delivery_date
          GROUP BY d.date";
```

Note that if an order matches multiple dates, it will be counted for each of them.